# Why the magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale as $1/T^2$ in knowledge distillation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In the paper ["Distilling the Knowledge in a Neural Network"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf), they claim that "*the magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale as $1/T^2$ it is important to multiply them by $T^2$ when using both hard and soft targets*".

In section 2.1, they write:

*Each case in the transfer set contributes a cross-entropy gradient, $dC/dz_i$, with respect to each logit, $z_i$ of the distilled model.
If the cumbersome model has logits $v_i$ which produce soft target probabilities $p_i$ and the transfer training is done at a temperature of $T$, this gradient is given by:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_i} = \frac{1}{T}(q_i - p_i) = \frac{1}{T}(\frac{e^{z_i/T}}{\sum_j e^{z_j/T}} - \frac{e^{v_i/T}}{\sum_j e^{v_j/T}}) \tag{2}
$$
If the (softmax) temperature is high compared with the magnitude of the logits, we can approximate:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_i} \approx \frac{1}{T}\left(\frac{1 + z_i/T}{N + \sum_j z_j/T} - \frac{1 + v_i/T}{N + \sum_j v_j/T}\right) \tag{3}
$$
If we now assume that the logits have been zero-meaned separately for each transfer case so that
$\sum_j z_j = \sum_j v_j = 0$ Eq. 3 simplifies to:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_i} \approx \frac{1}{NT^2} (z_i - v_i) \tag{4}
$$*

For hard targets, a cross-entropy gradient $dC/dz_i$, with respect to each logit, $z_i$ of the student model is
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_i} = (q_i - 1) = (\frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_j e^{z_j}} - 1) \tag{5}
$$

I can see that the $1/T^2$ term appears in Eq. 4, but why do they claim that the magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale as $1/T^2$? I can't see why Eq. 4 is $1/T^2$ of Eq. 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess.

For Eq.5, can approximate :

$$
\frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_j e^{z_j}} - 1 \approx \frac{z_i + 1}{\sum (1 + z_j)} - 1 \\
= \frac{1 + z_i}{N} - 1 \\
\approx \frac{z_i}{N}
$$

From Eq.4, can get :
$$
\frac{1}{T^2} \frac{z_i}{N}
$$
$v_i$ is not considered because it comes from the teacher model and is a definite number.

Finally, can get the gradient of CE is $T^2$ times the gradient of KL.

**Please note, I'm not sure this is right.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).